# C++ assign const reference to instance variable (memory issues?)

Tags: c++, memory-management, reference, stack, instance-variables

I always thought that references were functionally the same as pointers, they just have a much friendlier syntax, and some other minor differences ( references cannot be assigned to null, they cannot be reassigned).

But today I saw this code and I do not understand why it is correct:

There is simple struct, Color3B. We create one on the stack like this:

```
Color3B color(255,0,0);
```

There is another class, one of its instance variables is of Color3B type.

```
class Node{

private:
    Color3B _color;
public:
    void setColor(const Color3B& color){
        _color = color;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
void someFunction(){
    Color3B color(255,0,0);   
    _someNode->setColor(color);    
}
```

I think color is destroyed when it is out of scope: when someFunction ends. But setColor gets a memory address of something created on the stack, and stores it. But there are no issues, when I access Node's _color, it is always there and has a correct value.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `_color` and `color` are **not** referring to same memory hence the code is valid.

Comment: You could have compared the address of the parameter with that of the member, noticed that they were different, and concluded that they aren't the same object. With pointers your code would look like `void setColor(const Color3B* c) { _color = *c; } ... _someNode->setColor(&color);`. Would you expect `_color` to be invalid after the call?

Answer (score 8):

`_color = color;` takes a value copy of `color` so it doesn't matter that `color` eventually goes out of scope.

You'd have issues if the member variable `_color` was *itself* a reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
void someFunction(){
    Color3B color(255,0,0);    // (1)
    _someNode->setColor(color);// (2)  
}                              // (5)


void setColor(const Color3B& color){ // (2)(3)
    _color = color;                  // (4)
}
```

Let's see what happens here :

1. create an object named `color`
2. give it by reference to `setColor`
3. the parameter `color` is now a reference (alias) of `color`
4. copy the value of `color` into `_color` (assignment) because `_color` is not a reference
5. `color` is destroyed

Answer (score 1):

The error that you think should happen would happen if `_color` was a reference.

```
class Node{

private:
    const Color3B& _color;
public:
    void setColor(const Color3B& color){
        _color = color;
    }
};
```

This code would produce the error you expect. Now you actually would save the address of the color on stack into `Node` and that would be destroyed at the end of `someFunction()`. However you do not do that. Your `Node` has its own `Color3B` object, not a reference to it. So the code `_color = color` actually performs a copy from the color in `someFunction()` to the color in `Node` object. Now even if the original color gets destroyed, the one in `Node` lives on.

If you wrote `setColor()` with a pointer, the equivalent to your code would be:

```
void setColor(const Color3B* color){
    _color = *color;
}
```

Because a reference is not an address of a variable but an alias. So `color` in the above code (if it is a reference) represents the value of it, not the address. To get the address you would have to write `&color`.